# defocus button after clicking it

Tags: vb.net, focus

In a VB project I have 3 buttons (checkbox with buttons appearance). If I click 1 of them it remains selected (focused).

I will control that program with a small RF keyboard, I suffer of pressing the space key very easy!

How can I deselect (loose the focus) of that control to avoid the accidental activation-deactivation by space pressing?
I've tried adding a hidden button, and focusing it on the click event of the check-buttons"... like:

```
newbutton.focus()
```

but it doesn't work! Later I've tried to focus the mainform but also it doesn't work!

```
form1.focus()
```

also I've tried:

```
Form1.select()
```

but still no working after clicking(checking) the button it can be easily unchecked clicking the space key again! Which is the correct way to avoid the accidental unchecking?

thanks.

Comment: Only things the user can interact with can get the focus - that excludes hidden controls and the form.  Move the focus to another control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you working with a WinForm.  The Form as a property named [ActiveControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) that can be set to `Nothing` (null).  Doing so in the `CheckBox.CheckedChanged` handler, will *unfocus* the `CheckBox` and prevent the issue you are experiencing.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    Me.ActiveControl = Nothing
    ' any other necessary code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just disable the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keys completely for your check box(es)?

```
'This contains the list of keys that should be disabled from interacting with your check boxes.
'You can add or remove keys from this as you like.
Dim DisabledKeys As New HashSet(Of Keys) From {
    Keys.Enter, Keys.Space
}

Private Sub CheckBoxes_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.KeyDown, CheckBox2.KeyDown, CheckBox3.KeyDown
    e.SuppressKeyPress = DisabledKeys.Contains(e.KeyCode)
End Sub
```